# How to build classes for easiest understanding from consumers and testing

Tags: c#, class, design-patterns

I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure my classes for the consumers of the classes to be able to use them with the least amount of effort.

Given these two examples:

```
public class Foo
{

    public List<Bar> Bars { get; private set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        Bars = new List<Bar>();
        Method1();
        Method2();
    }

    private void Method1()
    {
        // code
    }

    private void Method2()
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

In this instance, the consumer of the class does not need to know how to consume the class, and (assuming method1/2 perform some operation on Bars) the user only needs to instantiate the class to get the information needed - Bars.

Or should this be done (or something different altogether):

```
public class Foo
{

    public List<Bar> Bars { get; private set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        Bars = new List<Bar>();
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Method1();
        Method2();
    }

    private void Method1()
    {
        // code
    }

    private void Method2()
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

In this instance, the consumer needs to know to call DoStuff() in order to use the class properly.  In cases where classes get bloated, this can be quite confusing to the user if they need to figure out the order in which methods are called. In this instance, and i know in best practices, classes *should* be thin and follow SRP, but if that were not the case is there a reason to go with one method compared to another?

Somewhat related, because my Method1 and Method2's manipulate data in my Bars, is there a rule/best practice on whether or not Method1 and Method2 take in parameters of List to then apply to Bars, or can it work directly with Bars without taking parameters into the object.  Is there a reason to do one over the other?

Comment: You'll probably find lots of answers if you search for RAII: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Comment: I'll look into that Peter, I have not heard of that term before now, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there ever a valid reason to *not* call these two methods when constructing the class?

Is there ever a valid reason to call these two methods at some point in time after an instance has been constructed?

Is it invalid to call these methods more than once on a given instance?

If any of the above are true, then that functionality isn't available in your first option, but it is in your second.  If that functionality is actually important, then the first option *doesn't provide the needed functionality.

If all of the above questions are a "no" then the second isn't really an option.  You're providing functionality to which the consumer can only ever do something wrong.  They're only ever breaking things by not doing exactly the right thing, so you might as well just do the right thing for them and not give them an opportunity to get it wrong.

If, on the other hand, the first option doesn't provide as much functionality as is needed, but there still are certain constraints that you have (i.e. not being able to invoke them multilpe times, but wanting to defer the work if possible, not being able to call other methods until this work is done, etc.) then odds are both are wrong.  You'll want to be very explicit about what your actual constraints are, as well as what all of the required (and possibly also nice-to-have) functionality is to try to find a solution that meets all of your constraints, while still providing all of the needed functionality.

Comment: Thanks @Servy that makes a lot of sense... I though I had read something about calling methods within the constructor being a bad idea somewhere, and just wanted to check myself... before i wreck myself.

Comment: @Kritner you do not want to throw an exception in the destructor, because this leads to exceptions being thrown during exceptions, which - in C++ - is terminal. Throwing an exception during construction means more thinking is required when writing the destructor.

Comment: @Kritner You shouldn't call *virtual* methods in the constructor.  These methods aren't virtual.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you already answered your own question. Do you have a more specific example that might make it more clear why you are considering the second example?

Constructors should do everything necessary to initialize the class so that it's ready to use, like the first example. Since Bars is read-only from the user's point of view, and since the DoStuff() method that apparently initializes the list of Bars and contained Bar objects don't take any parameters, it should be done in the constructor.